# Como hacer que mi json en Spring boot tengan llaves

Tags: java

estoy llamando un procedimiento almacenado en mi Entidad y lo llamo en mi servicio usando Spring boot 2, la cuestion es que el json me genera sin sus llaves respectivamente
Gracias

Hola amigos , estoy llamando un procedimiento almacenado en mi Entidad y lo llamo en mi servicio usando Spring boot 2, la cuestion es que el json me genera sin sus llaves respectivamente
Gracias

Hola amigos , estoy llamando un procedimiento almacenado en mi Entidad y lo llamo en mi servicio usando Spring boot 2, la cuestion es que el json me genera sin sus llaves respectivamente
Gracias

```js
package com.example.demo.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;


@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_usuario")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
 @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getUsuario", procedureName = "usp_usuario")
})
public class Usuarios implements Serializable{
 
 public Usuarios() {
  
 }

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 @Id
 @Column(name = "id_usuario")
 private int id_usuario;
 
 @NotEmpty(message = "no puede estar vacio")
 private String nombre;
 
 @NotEmpty(message = "no puede estar vacio")
 private String apellidopat;
 
 @NotEmpty(message = "no puede estar vacio")
 private String apellidomat;
 
 @NotEmpty(message = "no puede estar vacio")
    @Column(nullable = false)
 @Email(message = "de de tener un formato Email correcto")
 private String email;
 
 
  @Column(nullable = false, name = "foto_url")
 private String foto_url;


 public int getId_usuario() {
  return id_usuario;
 }


 public void setId_usuario(int id_usuario) {
  this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
 }


 public String getNombre() {
  return nombre;
 }


 public void setNombre(String nombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
 }


 public String getApellidopat() {
  return apellidopat;
 }


 public void setApellidopat(String apellidopat) {
  this.apellidopat = apellidopat;
 }


 public String getApellidomat() {
  return apellidomat;
 }


 public void setApellidomat(String apellidomat) {
  this.apellidomat = apellidomat;
 }


 public String getEmail() {
  return email;
 }


 public void setEmail(String email) {
  this.email = email;
 }


 public String getFoto_url() {
  return foto_url;
 }


 public void setFoto_url(String foto_url) {
  this.foto_url = foto_url;
 }
 
  
  
  

}
```

Mi clase Servicio

```js
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios;
import com.example.demo.repository.IUsuarioService;

@Transactional
@Service
public class UusuarioServices implements IUsuarioService {

 @Autowired
 private EntityManager em;
 
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
 public List<Usuarios> getUsuarios() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  List<Usuarios> usuario  = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getUsuario").getResultList();
  return usuario;
 }


 

}
```

Y en el postman sale asi sin sus llaves respectivamente

```js
[
    [
        2,
        "Marcos",
        "Marcos",
        "MAr",
        "mar@gmail.com",
        "123.jpg"
    ],
    [
        4,
        "Marcos",
        "Marcos",
        "MAr",
        "massr@gmail.com",
        "123.jpg"
    ]
]
```

Comment: falta tu controlador no?

Comment: El problema podría estar en tu controlados, podrías agregar el controlador para que se pueda verificar mejor.

Answer (score 0):

En el codigo del API que publicas estas retornando el objeto sin castearlo a un objeto serializable en JAVA, lo que debe hacer es modificar tu objeto de la siguiente manera.

```
package com.example.demo.services;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.entity.Usuarios;
import com.example.demo.repository.IUsuarioService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping('/prueba/stack')
public class UusuarioController implements IUsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<List<Usuarios>> getUsuarios() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Usuarios> usuario  = em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getUsuario").getResultList();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(usuario,HttpStatus.OK);
    }




}
```

Al pasarlo por un ResponseEntity y con tipo de codigo Http se parcea solo a un tipo de dato JSON, prueba con este cambio si no, genera un metodo sobre escrito llama ToString y parcealo a JSON para que tome la estrucutra que tu le quieras dar.